# Is there is way to update the data to user once changed without opening the app?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Recently, I'm working on an app which is used to set alarm to other users who are logged in to the app, But problem is how can I set alarm to other user when the data is changed in the real-time database of firebase. Is there is any way that if I update the data of other user and It should to retrieved and updated in other users application and alarm should set when data is received.

---

```
 DatabaseReference duser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Alarm");
                duser.keepSynced(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
                duser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String ids = snapshot.child(id).getKey();
                        Log.d("ID   : ", ids+"");
                        String hour = snapshot.child(id).child("hour").toString();
                        Log.d("HOUR :  ", hour+"");
                        String minute = snapshot.child(id).child("minute").toString();
                    }
```

---

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvPGT.png)
This is my database.

If yes please explain me, how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does [Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) method it:

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.

This means that you'll get the data only once, without future updates. If you want a persistent listener to listen for real-time changes, then you  use [Query#addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) that:

> Add a listener for changes in the data at this location.

So each time something is added, changed, or deleted you're notified almost instantly. If you want, you can also use a library for that, which is called [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Comment: Yeah it actually worked but what if user want get notification whenever the changes happen in their data?

Comment: That definitely possible using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging).